# Will Puppy Linux make Google Drive go smoother my old netbook?

Tags: linux, performance, google-drive, lubuntu, puppylinux

I'm trying to reactivate an old Intel Learning Series netbook, for educational purposes. I'd like to use it to explain my high-school pupils basics of online, multi-platform, office tools, especially google drive, docs, sheets.

It's running Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

The hardware specs (as listed on System data) are:

- CPU: Intel Atom CPU N455 @1.66Ghz - 1 physical processor, 1 core, 2 threads
- RAM: 10111196 KiB
- HDD: 160GB SAMSUNG HM161GI

As you might expect, it runs Google Drive quite slowly (i've been using it from Firefox)

**Will it make a performance difference if I move to Puppy Linux?**

I mean, using Puppy Linux would make such a task as using google drive more fluent, or will it keep it the same, due to hardware limits?

Other suggestions other than Puppy Linux are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puppy Linux should help - but don't expect to much.

That system is very old. (it was entry level 10 years ago). It is constrained by memory, cpu and using a hard drive.  I do note that it must be using a lot of swap - which is very slow - as that cpu can only handle 2 gigs of memory max - so the 10 gigs being reported must be at least 8 gigs swap, and this is a problem a lightweight distro can help with.

You will still be left with a system less powerful then a typical modern cellphone.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similarly specced netbook (Asus eeePC), until very recently.  It originally had Windows 7 starter.  However, while it could run Windows 10, it was awful.  I put various Linux distros on it, but settled on MX Linux, a "midweight" distro.  It was very slow, but acceptable for the little I used it for.  I ended up upgrading it to 2GB of RAM and a SSD and it was definitely faster, but still no speed demon.  Atom CPUs are just not that fast, especially on a ~10 year old netbook.  Upgrading the RAM to the max and a cheap SSD will help no matter what OS you choose.